# NSMutableArray property automatically reset in TableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, uitableview, nsnotificationcenter

I am currently trying to get a NSMutableArray property on my TableViewController updated from an NSNotification but facing issues.

I have declared my property in the Observer class .h file as below:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *cart;
```

Synthesize in Observer class .m file:

```
@synthesize cart = _cart;
```

I am receiving the notification in the AwakeFromNib method of the Observer Class:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib{

if (!self.cart){
    NSLog(@"self.cart == nil");
    self.cart = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}else{
    NSLog(@"self.cart != nil");
}

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(addCurrentItemToCartFromNotification:) name:@"ItemAddedToCart" object:nil];
}
```

Please note that I am performing the alloc init of my NSMutableArray property in the above AwakeFromNib method before receiving the notification.

This is the method that is called upon receipt of the notification:

```
- (void)addCurrentItemToCartFromNotification:(NSNotification *)notification{

 NSDictionary *currentItem = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"CART_ITEM_INFORMATION"];

[self.cart addObject:currentItem];
[self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

I then have my tableview datasource methods based on my NSMutableArray property that is updated in the above methods from the notification.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [self.cart count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"itemInCart";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...
NSDictionary *cartItem = [self.cart objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [cartItem objectForKey:@"ITEM_NAME"];

return cell;
}
```

My expected behavior from the program is to update my NSMutable array property very time the notification is received(The alloc init should happen only the very first time because of the if (!self.cart) condition)

But what is happening is every time I receive a notification, the object in the NSMutableArray is deleted and the new one is added instead of appending. Hence at any point in time, the NSMutableArray only contains the object received fomr the most recent notification.

I am thinking the alloc init is happening every time as opposed to just the very first time.

Could you please tell me what I am missing here. I would really appreciate your inputs on this issue.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: You need to set the array before you bring it into your file.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code. Try logging self.cart right after you add an item to it, and see what it shows.

Comment: Also, are you seeing "self.cart == nil" being printed out multiple times (or "self.cart != nil", for that matter. awakeFromNib should only be called once, unless your class is being dealloc'd)?

Comment: @rdelmar - I am seeing "self.cart == nil" everytime I am adding an item to it.

Comment: That means this class is being dealloc'd. How are you creating this class? Do you alloc init it from another class?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're seeing that array reallocated (if that's what's going on), but this calls for a different pattern anyway: I'd lazy init your cart property by replacing the synthesized setter...

```
- (NSArray *)cart {
    if (!_cart) {
        _cart = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return _cart;
}
```

Delete that cart stuff in awakeFromNib, and always refer to self.cart (except in init and dealloc).

Comment: I am still facing the same issue. Couple of questions though:

1) Does it matter that the whole thing is in a tab view cntrlr and I am sending the NSNotfctn from Tab A and all the above code for receiving the NSNotfctn, adding to the array etc are happening in the tableviewcontroller which is Tab B?

2) I added an NSLog in your cart method as below:

`- (NSArray *)cart {
    if (!_cart) {
        NSLog(@"self.cart == nil");
        _cart = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    NSLog(@"self.cart != nil");
    return _cart;
}`

Now every time I post the notification NsLog shows "self.cart != nil".

Comment: As it should, right?  You can help your debugging by logging the cart itself, like this NSLog(@"cart is %@", _cart);  Log it right after you add an item, then log it in your numberOfRowInSection method.  Are the counts consistent?  Does the array's address change?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you're getting "self.cart == nil" logged each time you add an entry means that awakeFromNib is being called every time you add an entry, which in turn means that you're creating a new instance of Observer class each time. So that's the problem, not any of the code that's in your post. To fix the problem, we need to know how you create this class.